# How to set specific value of DISPLAY variable on remote host with SSH but without command line parameters?

Tags: ssh, configuration, environment-variables

In putty I can configure exact values for environment variables on remote host, for example

[image]

On Linux I have `~/.ssh/config` file which contains entry like this

```
Host calculon
    User dims
```

Is it possible and how to configure remote host environment variables on Linux in the same way i.e. without specifying them on command line or separate commands?

I can specify

```
SendEnv DISPLAY
```

in `config`, but this will require to set this variable on local host via separate command. This is both excessive and for `DISPLAY` variable is also a nonsense.

Also I have read about `~/.ssh/environment` file and wrote this

```
dims@pterosaur:~$ cd .ssh
dims@pterosaur:~/.ssh$ cat environment 
DISPLAY=pterosaur:0
```

but this has no effect (variable `DISPLAY` is not set on remote host).

Note that `sshd` is already configured to accept `DISPLAY` variable and accepts it normally from `Putty`. So the task is to configure Linux client in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration is documented in [`man 5 ssh_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config).

*SendEnv* can be used if the server supports and is configured to accept it:

> **SendEnv**
>
> Specifies what variables from the local `environ(7)` should be sent to the server. Note that environment passing is only supported for protocol 2. The server must also support it, and the server must be configured to accept these environment variables. Refer to `AcceptEnv` in `sshd_config(5)` for how to configure the server. Variables are specified by name, which may contain wildcard characters. Multiple environment variables may be separated by whitespace or spread across multiple SendEnv directives. The default is not to send any environment variables.

If that is not possible you can also configure remote host shell with your environmental variables (using `.profile` etc., for bash see documentation on [bash startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files)).

Comment: This will pass current environment variable to remote host, but not set it

Comment: You could write alias or wrapper for your local shell to set those variables. I am not aware that you can directly set those in `ssh_config`.

Comment: What about any other ways? But without writing a wrapper.

Comment: @Dims `FOO=bar; ssh -t user@host "FOO=$FOO /bin/bash -l"`. Or, if the server has `FOO` in its `AcceptEnv`: `FOO=bar ssh -o SendEnv=FOO user@host`

Comment: @Dims tl;dr; you don't have to set an envvar via a different command as you claim in your question; `key=value command` sets `key` **only** in the environment of `command`.